# Bluetooth 2.1 EDR sniffer

Tags: bluetooth

I'm new to Bluetooth technology and I'm trying to find something capable of sniffing Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR data. I see a lot of BLE/4.0 related devices.

So far the closest things I've found were:

- [PAN1315](http://www.em.avnet.com/en-us/design/drc/Pages/Texas-Instruments-PAN1315-Bluetooth-Evaluation-Module-Kit-for-MSP430.aspx)
- [FTS4BT](http://www.fte.com/products/fts4bt.aspx)

Has anyone tried sniffing BT 2.1+EDR packets before? If so, what solutions were used? Has anyone tried the above modules and can provide some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

The only Bluetooth sniffer for classic Bluetooth (i.e. not Bluetooth 4.0/Smart) that is in a hobbyist's price range is the "Ubertooth One": http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/

For a list of places you can buy it, check out https://greatscottgadgets.com/ubertoothone/

Of course you have commercial bluetooth sniffers from for example Ellisys and Frontline, the latter being the more venerable of the two:

- http://www.ellisys.com/products/bex400/
- http://www.fte.com/products/fts4bt.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions(+1) I'll contact the commercial bluetooth sniffer providers and see how that works. I need to sniff Bluetooth 2.1+EDR packets and Dominic from Uberbooth informed me: "
There is no version of Ubertooth which can sniff EDR packets and we have yet to identify a chipset that would allow us to build one."

Comment: just a quick update: techinically linux systems should be able to explicitly not use EDR. Also, the commercial sniffers above are **ridiculously** expensive